# What's the name for this part on a Cessna 172P?

Tags: feature-identification, cessna-172, doors

I am trying to figure out what the name for this part is.

[image]

I believe that's the door seal, but all seals I am looking at, seem to be glued to the outside now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s part of the interior trim, which has come dislodged from the fuselage side near the door.

Comment: Trim, yes. It appears to have shrunk over time. Door seal is a V-shaped material that is glued to the door (and not pictured here). Order a new trim piece from Plane Plastics in OK. http://www.planeplastics.com/airplanes/cessna-single/172175/

Comment: @CrossRoads I'd also order a thorough inspection of the entire aircraft. I an see the corrosion on some of the interior without blowing up the image, looks like this aircraft hasn't been properly looked after in years if not decades.

Comment: I think that the rusty looking stuff is just old glue. There is some surface rust around the door latch, but it will probably come off with a bit of rubbing with wax or Tri-Flow.

Comment: That's exactly my plan. Unfortunately the previous owner hasn't put much effort into the plane, so I am planning on giving it a lot of love.